# Pull elements based on properties without removing them Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, observable

I know this must be simple with computed observables somehow but I can't get it to work.

I have an observable array Items that have the property isSelected (true/false). i want to get all items that have isSelected set to true. I wrote a little function that does that fairly easily:

```
self.selectedItems = function () {
    var selected = self.Items.remove(function (item) { return item.isSelected; })
    return selected;
}
```

But as you'd expect, remove pops these items out of the array. Is there a function to replace remove() in this case, such as get(). Or more likely the correct route of turning this whole function into some sort of computed observable get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (in a computed/pureComputed):

```
ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Items(), function(item) { return item.isSelected; });
```

Comment: Perfect, I was just toying with arrayFilter() but wasn't working at all, this did it though (will accept when allowed)